# Android Volley OnErrorResponse

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have JSON request with volley in my model class and obviously in my code I have onError response and my JSON request is not in activity class how can I make alert user when error is occurred during retrieving the data, I used `toast.makeText` as can be seen but application terminates 
here is my code:

```
public class EdaModel {
    String TAG ="Eda Model";
    private static  Context mContext;

    private static EdaModel ourInstance = new EdaModel();

    public static EdaModel getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ArrayList<Eda> edaList = new ArrayList<Eda>();

    public ArrayList<Eda> getEdaList() {
        return edaList;
    }

    private EdaModel() {

    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONArray> netListener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse (JSONArray response){
            //Clean edaList from old data
            edaList.clear();

            try {
                for(int i=0; i<response.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Eda eda = new Eda (
                            obj.getInt("record_id"),
                            obj.getString("title"),
                            obj.getString("short_info"),
                            obj.getString("date"),
                            obj.getString("image_url")
                    );
                        edaList.add(eda);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //parsing error in JSON data
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error:" +e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            notifyListener();
        }
    };

    private Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error:" +error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    };

        //load the JSON data called by Adapter
        public void loadData(){
            //Create a request object
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest("http://........",netListener,errorListener
            );
                    //Submit Request
                    EdaApp.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);

            }
         private OnListUpdateListener listUpdateListener;

                public void setOnListUpdateListener (OnListUpdateListener listUpdateListener){
                    this.listUpdateListener = listUpdateListener;
                }

                public interface OnListUpdateListener {
                void onListUpdate (ArrayList<Eda> edaList);

            }

            private void notifyListener (){
                if(listUpdateListener != null)

                listUpdateListener.onListUpdate(edaList);
            }


          public static Context getContext(){
              return mContext;
          }
          public static void setContext(Context context){
              context = mContext;
          }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Dear j_Vega thanks for your reply I sorted it out I added toast message by getting relevant activitity's context I found my mistake at the bottom of the page as you can see there is a method set context inside the method mContext = context(which comes from main activity)